# How to link windows lib on travis ci?

Tags: c++, github, travis-ci

I am working on github and now I am trying to import travis ci on my project related to

```
-lwsock32 -liphlpapi
```

These are libraries existing on windows system and they are used because my project works on windows platform.
Is it possible to enable autobuild of travis ci in this situation?
my project is in https://github.com/jadecubes/Utilities
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Where is your `.travis.yml`?  [Did you set `os` to `windows`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/windows/#using-windows)?

Comment: Thanks for the reminding. I have checked in a .travis.yml file, a modified version from the linux .travis.yml. But since I don't know how to discribe the addon, I leave it there as it is. Any advice is appreciated.